# CBL Mariner VS Ubuntu for AKS

Tags: ubuntu, azure-aks

Recently I started exploring about CBL Mariner for AKS, currently my aks cluster are running in Ubuntu. When i strated reading about Mariner - CBL-Mariner Linux is a lightweight operating system, containing only the packages needed for a cloud environment by MS.

https://microsoft.github.io/CBL-Mariner/docs/

But, What are the real differences between Mariner Vs Ubuntu ?
What benefits I am going to get if I adopt Mariner things like patching, auto upgrade of node pools, version, SSH, security etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [AKS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-mariner):

> The Mariner container host on AKS uses a native AKS image that
> provides one place to do all Linux development. Every package is built
> from source and validated, ensuring your services run on proven
> components. Mariner is lightweight, only including the necessary set
> of packages needed to run container workloads. It provides a reduced
> attack surface and eliminates patching and maintenance of unnecessary
> packages. At Mariner's base layer, it has a Microsoft hardened kernel
> tuned for Azure. Learn more about the key capabilities of Mariner.

Since this is created by Microsoft for Microsoft, you can expect the following:

- Faster release cycles
- Faster bug/security fixes
- Less OS related issues
- Might have better performance due to it being tuned for MS hardware.

Keep in mind that Mariner is still in preview, and would not be recommended for production use.

Comment: This is great but can you point me towards difference between Ubuntu Vs Mariner ?

Comment: i mean thats the value prop. less packages, faster boot, faster patch, less attack surface, etc. i doubt anyone would be able to give you a LIST of things that are different between ubuntu and mariner

Comment: Faster bug/security fixes - actually the opposite is true. On unamanged AKS channel, Ubuntu is patched for security automatically and Azure Linux is not and requires manual update.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the official reasons provided by [akathimi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75459209/cbl-mariner-vs-ubuntu-for-aks/75459434#75459434), in my case, the AKS memory WorkingSet has dropped by ~20% after switching from Ubuntu to Mariner.

Comment: This seems a comment rather than an answer

Comment: Maybe. Let's user voting decide whether this "real difference" is useful or not. Not everyone reads all comments.

Comment: In fact, the question was specifically about "real differences/benefits" and not about general well-known things "like patching, auto upgrade of node pools, version, SSH, security etc".

Comment: Can you ellaborate more on AKS memory working set dropped by ~20 % ?

Comment: The working set was about 110% but become 90% after switching. What kind of additional info you're interested in?

Comment: PS. Other metrics (like MemoryRSS, CPU, etc.) remained unchanged